# Removing Last Empty/Blank Line from Textbox (textarea) with VBScript or Javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, textarea, lines

Ok, with the help of Sigfried I got through my last question. Now that I have implemented his suggestion I have parsed information into a textarea textbox and when I do there is a line at the bottom that is empty/blank. Since I will be taking this data and inserting it into a database it cannot have a null value being inserted so I need to remove this last empty line. I am doing this in VB ASP so I am open for suggestions in either VBScript or Javascript.

This is the actual code using VBScript pulling in information from a database table and repeating each table row:

```
<textarea name="output2" cols="50" rows="5" id="output2">
<% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT ReadCC.EOF)) %>
<%=(ReadCC.Fields.Item("NUMBER").Value + vbCr) %>
<% Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  ReadCC.MoveNext()
  Wend %>
</textarea>
```

When this happens on the page this is what is shown in the source:

```
<td style="color:#000000;">
 <div align="center">
  <textarea name="output2" cols="50" rows="5" id="output2">1234657812345678
8765432187654321
  </textarea>
 </div></td>
```

While it is hard to tell with the code above, there is a blank line after 654321 and that is because of the repeat region putting in a vbCr after each line.

I thought about doing a Replace() or a Regex.Replace() but when I try to put these in I end up with server errors. If I get up to reputation 10 I will edit this and put in a screen shot of the textbox.

Comment: you can remove the hard-coded line between `Wend %>` and `</textarea>`

Comment: Thanks, I actually put that in to this question just so the formatting was cleaner. In my code there is no line between %> and </textarea>.

Comment: instead of always appending the break, you can "echo" the vbCr in a conditional (not eof) after the movenext() and before the Wend, or just trim() it in sql as it gets inserted. in general, the DB should be in charge of this sort of housekeeping, not the client.

Comment: Can you put in an example of the "echo" vbCr for me? I can trial and error until I get it but it would be easier with an example. Thanks

Comment: I believe I did what you said but I think I put it in the wrong place. I put a Response.Write(vbCr) right above the ReadCC.MoveNext(). It still successfully put each set of digits on a new line but also still created an empty line at the end. I started checking to see if SQL cared and it doesn't seem to so now I will post a new question here on SO to see how I can insert the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write vbCR if you are not at last record:

```
<textarea name="output2" cols="50" rows="5" id="output2">
<% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT ReadCC.EOF)) %>
<%=(ReadCC.Fields.Item("NUMBER").Value) %>
<% Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  ReadCC.MoveNext()
  if not ReadCC.eof then response.write vbCR
  Wend %>
</textarea>
```

Comment: This worked! I actually put in **If (NOT ReadCC.EOF) Then Response.Write(vbCR)** before the ReadCC.MoveNext(). Thank you Ali and dandavis for this path.